# Extract sub string from XML tag with more than one line using awk/sed

Tags: xml, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have an XML file which contain many Account tags which will contain few other Tags which include RecordNumber and OriginalData. I would like to compare 2 numbers from that XML file, one from RecordNumber tag and other from OriginalData - which is exactly 6 charactors after part_name. ideally these 2 numbers should be equal, but some how they are not same in some files for some xml tags.

Using awk or sed would be great???

Here a sample fo my XML file.

```
....
<Account>
.......
<RecordNumber>224</RecordNumber>
......
  <OriginalData><![CDATA[E0000003350000077558part_name              89947                                         0123456789012345                                            C2016-01-08T13:04:41-05:00001004000000000000000035.000000000000000000035.000                      US034F93Geg824G36L8F                                                                                               0002                                                                                                                                                                                 
.....
```

....

Thanks for your help.

Comment: <Account>
<RecordNumber>224</RecordNumber>
<OriginalData><![CDATA[E0000003350000077558part_name              89947                                         0123456789012345                                            C2016-01-08T13:04:41-05:00001004000000000000000035.000000000000000000035.000                      US034F93Geg824G36L8F                                                                                               0002 
</OriginalData>
</Account>

Comment: I am sorry, this is the 1st time im adding code, so couldnt able to add clearly, sorry for the bad format.

Comment: Try first post the code you already done. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting to learn format your question and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to how to ask.

Comment: I have another suggestion here: don't use sed/awk to process xml files, try xml library for your favourity programing language (streaming one if you have a lot of data) or use xml processing tools like xmlstartlet.

Comment: That's **xmlstarlet**.  (It is somewhat startling.)

Answer (score 0):

```
 cat file.xml | sed -e "s/^.*RecordNumber>\([0-9]*\)<\/RecordNumber.*part_name *\([0-9]*\) *.*$/RecordNumber=\1\npart_name=\2/g"
```

Comment: Any code-only answer would be a better answer with an explanation as to why and how it works. Also, no need for `cat` here - sed takes a filename as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather long shell script. It will capture the RecordNumber and the part_name number into different files. Then it uses `diff` to find the different number. If there are any differences you would look up this number in your xml file.

```
cat FILE.xml | 
sed -zr ' 
        # normalize xml, insert newlines for RecordNumber and part_name
        s#</?RecordNumber>#\n&\n#g ; 
        s/part_name.{6}/\n&\n/g ;  
 ' | 
 sed -rn '
         # write the numbers into different files
        /<RecordNumber>/,/<\/RecordNumber>/ { 
                /[0-9]+/ { w rval.txt
                p;
                } 
        }
        /part_name/ {
                s/part_name[ ]+//g;
                w pval.txt
                p;
        }
 '
# compare the numbers
diff rval.txt pval.txt
```